# Autoloader in PHP, without composer or any other libraries for non-class files

Tags: php, autoload

I have been searching around about autoloader and every solution I have been found was about the classes (SPL autoload), composer and so on.

So I was thinking, what about non-class files, where I have some functions, some procedural code, etc.

I know about this one method, but it's not a really good solution for me.

```php
$RequiredFiles = array(
    '/functions/function1.php',
    '/functions/function2.php',
    '/procedural/code1.php',
    '/procedural/code2.php',
    ....
);
foreach ($RequiredFiles as $File) {
    $Path = __DIR__ . $File;
    require $Path;
}
```

My question is, how I can make an autoloader for non-class files?

I don't want to do something like this

```php
foreach (glob('/functions/*.php') as $File) {
   if( $File !== '/functions/donotincludethis.php'){
     require $File;
   }
}
```

I want to have some better and secure way to do that, of course **without composer.**

Comment: Namespace / create your own lib a level up from those functions and procedural sub folders..? Follow existing patterns. Recommended reading: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: How would you want this to work? Should all those functions just be always loaded, or are you thinking there would actually be some kind of mechanism like autoloading where they're only loaded if they're used?

Comment: In my case, it will be always loaded. Because I use, most of them in the whole app

Comment: Composer has [class map](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) functionality to deal with this exact case.  If you do not want to use composer for whatever reason, you simply need to implement a `spl_autoload_register()` callback function to find the class by name.

Comment: I talking about non-class files.

Comment: @NemanjaJeremic Sorry, my bad; composer can load non-class files just fine as well using the files directive right below.  See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Comment: As I said, without a composer. I cannot use the composer. Thas way I need another solution

Comment: The advantage of autoloading is that it can load a class file when the class is needed and PHP has tools to achieve this. There's no equivalent concept of "trigger this function if I try to call an undefined function" so you will have to pre-load all function containing files. I don't think there's a way around this

Comment: Sidenote: There seems to be a [draft proposal](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/function_autoloading) for this coming and going since 2013 but does not seem to be going anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Only classes and interfaces can be autoloaded.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) It doesn't make sense for "procedural code files" to be autoloaded; how would you even refer to them except with `require 'file.php'`? Functions *could* theoretically be autoloaded but practically PHP doesn't allow it, so for including function definitions you'll still need to use `require_once 'my_funcs.php'` at the top of your file.

Comment: I agree with what for the procedural code. But, what if you need to require some big number of files, it will be crazy if I do something like in my first example. Then I'll have a big list of files. Okay, then I can use the second example, but what if I don't want to require some of the files in that folder. It will be crazy to make another foreach loop inside the first one, which one will read data from a new array where I will declare, what the files I don't want to require.

Comment: In each file where you require a function from one of your custom files, you put a `require_once` at the top to ensure that that file is loaded. If you end up with a ton of those statements in all files, then perhaps you should refactor into smaller files; it’s a good smell test. In a reasonably scoped file it’s not atypical to have some dozen or so import statements at the top, which is manageable. A good IDE will generate those for you almost automatically while you type your code. Under virtually no circumstances is it sensible to loop through a whole directory of stuff and include it.

Comment: Can you provide, what you should do if you **must** have some `load.php` file, where you gonna require a bunch of files, with exceptions *(what files you don't want to require)*? It's there any standard which one I need to follow?

Comment: *Why* is this a "must"? Autoloading solves two problems: 1) so you don't have to type a bunch of `require_once` statements, but 2) so classes are loaded *when needed*, and not all upfront. Since you can't do point #1 for functions, you should still do #2 for functions: require them *if and when you need them*. Typically that means just on the files that you use them in. Why do you think it's a good idea to just blindly load everything upfront?

Answer (score -1):

Automatic loading is to solve the dependencies that the code needs to run. I think of a method, which is similar to a container. The name of the dependency of the code you need to solve depends on the key of the array. The value of this array is the PHP file to be imported. The `require_once` function is recommended.